# Slow loading tableview on iPhone with reusable cells

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I load the data from Parse.com backend, they send me a solutions for use the reusable cells but now I still have troubles with the loading speed, this is the coding I have in my tableview and I have a Subclass for making up my cells (ExploreStreamCustomCell.m)

```
    - (ExploreStreamCustomCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
                        object:(PFObject *)object 
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ExploreStreamCustomCell";

    ExploreStreamCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ExploreStreamCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle 
                                              reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.listItemTitle.text = [object objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.checkinsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [object objectForKey:@"checkins"]];
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"description"];


    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    PFFile *listThumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"header"];
    cell.listViewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"loading_image_stream.png"]; // placeholder image
    cell.listViewImage.file = listThumbnail;
    [cell.listViewImage loadInBackground:NULL];

    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForNextPageAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.font = [cell.textLabel.font fontWithSize:kPAWWallPostTableViewFontSize];
    return cell;
}
```

If I have all the content of the //configure cell in the cell == nil the it's fast but it show up 3 of the 9 unique datarows and repeat those 3 unique content cell 3 times?

Edit extra code within  ExploreStreamCustomCell.m

```
#import "ExploreStreamCustomCell.h"

@implementation ExploreStreamCustomCell

@synthesize listViewImage, 
iconLocation, 
iconPeople, 
iconCheckins, 
listItemTitle, 
locationLabel, 
peopleLabel, 
checkinsLabel, 
descriptionLabel,
listItemView;


- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if(self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]){
        //Initialization code
        listItemView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        listViewImage = [[PFImageView alloc] init];
        iconLocation = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        iconPeople = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        iconCheckins = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        listItemTitle = [[UILabel alloc] init];     
        locationLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
        peopleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        checkinsLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init]; 
        descriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];

        listViewImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"nachtwacht_list_formaat.png"];
        iconLocation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_magenta_location.png"];
        iconPeople.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_magenta_people.png"];
        iconCheckins.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_magenta_checkins.png"];
        listItemTitle.text = @"text";
        locationLabel.text = @"0,7 km";
        peopleLabel.text = @"34";
        checkinsLabel.text = @"61";
        descriptionLabel.text = @"Description text.";

        [self.contentView addSubview:listItemView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:listViewImage];
        [self.contentView addSubview:iconLocation];
        [self.contentView addSubview:iconPeople];
        [self.contentView addSubview:iconCheckins];
        [self.contentView addSubview:listItemTitle];
        [self.contentView addSubview:locationLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:peopleLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:checkinsLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:descriptionLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;
    CGRect frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+0 , 33, 280, 124);
    listViewImage.frame = frame;
    listViewImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    listViewImage.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    //listViewImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+20 , 164, 12, 18);
    iconLocation.frame = frame;
    //iconLocation.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+102 , 164, 24, 18);
    iconPeople.frame = frame;
    //iconPeople.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+193 , 164, 20, 16);
    iconCheckins.frame = frame;
    //iconLocation.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+0 , 0, 280, 33);
    listItemView.frame = frame;
    listItemView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.749 green:0.000 blue:0.243 alpha:1.000];


    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+20 , 3, 240, 29);
    listItemTitle.frame = frame;
    //listItemTitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f/255.0f green:194.0f/255.0f blue:9.0f/255.0f alpha:0.8f];
    listItemTitle.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    listItemTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
    listItemTitle.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    listItemTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    listItemTitle.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    //listItemTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+40 , 164, 57, 21);
    locationLabel.frame = frame;
    locationLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    locationLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    locationLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.749 green:0.000 blue:0.243 alpha:1.000];
    locationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    locationLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    locationLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    //locationLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+134 , 164, 57, 21);
    peopleLabel.frame = frame;
    peopleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    peopleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    peopleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.749 green:0.000 blue:0.243 alpha:1.000]; 
    peopleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    peopleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    peopleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+221 , 164, 51, 21);
    checkinsLabel.frame = frame;
    checkinsLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    checkinsLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12];
    checkinsLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.749 green:0.000 blue:0.243 alpha:1.000]; 
    checkinsLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    checkinsLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    checkinsLabel.numberOfLines = 1;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+0 , 189, 280, 55);
    descriptionLabel.frame = frame;
    descriptionLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    descriptionLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
    descriptionLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
    descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 3;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


/*
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: In general there is no point in moving all that code to within the cell==nil branch of the if statement.

Comment: Where do you think gets the time lost? I'd try adding NSLog statements like NSLog(@"<%@:%d>", [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:__FILE__] lastPathComponent],  __LINE__]; to determin if and where within my mehtod the time is spent.

Comment: Please provide some code of ExploreStreamCustomCell, especially of its loadInBackground method. I'd guess that the time is consumed there.

Comment: Thnx Herman, I have provide the custom cell and I will test the code with the NSLog

Comment: Renaming the listViewImage to the original imageView was fixing the problem! Parse.com SDK is only using the cell.imageView for background downloading... So now I have an easy scrolling and lazy loading tableview!

Comment: Doing calculations in layoutSubviews will always slow down the tableview and doing that in cell is a disaster, as it gets called for every cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to explore the inefficiencies of your code is to use Instruments' Time Profiler tool. The Time Profiler will let you see how much time is being spent on each task, line-by-line in your code.

[image: Time Profiler]

---

I would recommend the following settings for profiling:

[image: Profiler settings]

---

From Apple's Face Detection sample app:

[image: Face Detection]

---

You can then double click any line (higher percentages mean more time is being devoted to that method call) to see in the code how much time is spent in each place.

[image: Code analysis]

---

From here you can begin to figure out where you are being inefficient and see exactly what is taking up so much time. Good luck!

Comment: Oke, thnx... but I don't see where to click on to see your screen with the code?

Call Tree is empty and the Sample List is not showing your 3th screenshot expample

Comment: Are you testing on a real device or the simulator?